# How to remove git ignored files from GitX Staged area

Tags: git, gitx

I removed some files from git index , using `git rm --cached`.

Those files were already staged before.
Now those files still shows at the GitX stage area, with red icon near them.
I would like them disappear, that's the reason I ignored them.

I tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged` to no avail.

Any advice ?

Comment: So GitX is showing you something different from the actual index? Even after closing and reopening it?

Comment: Also, your title says "ignored" - are they actually in your .gitignore? You never mention that in your question.

Comment: Yes, even after closing it. They are now in .gitignore, but I already tracked them before adding to the .gitingnore, so that didn't help. I tried removing them from the index, and they are removed (I assume by the red GitX icon, any other way to make sure ? ), but I want them to disappear completely from GitX , is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GitX manual](http://gitx.frim.nl/user_manual.html):

> A red icon indicates a file that has been deleted.

Meaning your `git rm --cached` did modify the staging area shown by GitX, marking those files to be deleted from the cache (and not the working tree) on the next commit.
All you need to do for them to actually disappear the GUI (from the staging area or "staged Changes" part of GitX) is to commit them.

Comment: Hey, Why would I want to commit them ? I don't want them to be pushed to the remote repo, that's why I ignored them. I'm a git beginner, so please explain. btw, by working tree does it really mean working directory ? I assumed that the "-- cached" will just remove them from git, and let them stay on the file system. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Idan: by commit them, I meant: "commit the fact those files, while still being present in the working tree, are now deleted in the Git repo from now on". That way, your gitignore will apply and Git will ignore those files. (they are now "private", as in "visible only in your local working tree").

Comment: a '`git rm --cached`' is only the first step, modifying the staging area. As long as you don't commit, the current modifications (to be committed, that is the role of the staging area) won't be part of your local Git history.